# Why can I not get past the HP title page to bios

Tags: motherboard, bios, boot

replaced motherboard on HP dv9700 and when powered up it only goes to the HP page and stops.  Anyone got any ideas on where to go next?

Comment: Can you get into BIOS? Pressing/tapping f2 after you press the power button?

Answer (score 0):

Check if everything is connected properly, try booting without HDD and CD drive. Also check if it will boot only on battery/only on AC.